# Why aren't my images displaying in Laravel app?

Tags: php, html, laravel, filepath

I am currently working on a new Laravel application and am trying to give users the ability to upload images to the local server. For purposes of this app, I refer to images as 'media'. First things first, here is my `media.create` file that allows users to upload the image:

```
<form method="POST" action="/media" class="form-signin" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Add Media</h2>

    <hr>

    <h2>Game Selector</h2>

    <select name="game_id">

        @foreach ($games as $game)

        <option name="game_id" value="{{ $game->id }}">{{ $game->opponent }} {{ $game->gdatetime }} {{ $game->season->year }}</option>

        @endforeach

    </select>


    <label for="inputMedia" class="sr-only">Media Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="file_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Media Name" required autofocus>

    <label for="inputMedia" class="sr-only">Content/Caption</label>
    <input type="text" name="content" class="form-control" placeholder="Caption/Content" required>

    <label for="inputMedia" class="sr-only">File</label>
    <input type="file" name="media_file" class="form-control" placeholder="File" required>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Here is the MediaController store function that saves images to the server

```
public function store() 
{

    //request()->file('media_file')->store('media');

    $media = Media::create(request(['game_id', 'file_name', 'content']));

    request()->file('media_file')->storeAs('media', $media->file_name.'.jpg', 'local');

    return redirect('/admin');

}
```

This works all fine and dandy. When I upload an image it appears in my `storage/app/media` folder, but when I try to retrieve the images in my `media.index` view the images are not displaying. Here is my `media.index`:

```
@foreach ($medias as $media)

<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12">

<h1 class="media_content">
{{ $media->game->gdatetime->format('l F jS \\, Y') }} vs.
{{ $media->game->opponent }}
</h1>


<a href="#"><img src="{{asset('storage/app/media').'/'.$media->file_name.'.jpg'}}" alt="{{ $media->file_name }}" height="250" width="250"></a>

<p class="media_content">
{{ $media->content }}
</p>

</div>

@endforeach
```

Why are my images not displaying on the `media.index` view? I assume it has to be something to do with the file path, but I have tried every combination I can think of that would make sense, and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `storage` folder from the web. `storage/app/media` will never be accessible. If you're using public disk (which creates a symlink from from `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`) then store the images to `storage/app/public/media`. The images can now be accessed from `/public/storage/media`. So your image source would be.

```
src="{{ asset("storage/media/{$media->file_name}.jpg") }}"
```

If you do not use public disk then upload anywhere under the root `public` folder and access it accordingly.

Documentation on public disk https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Hmmm this is still not working. Should I be able to see the files within public/storage/media if I open it from finder? Because I do not. I'm thinking I shouldn't because this path just represents a symlink to storage/app/public/media but I'm wondering if that is where issue is?

Comment: If the symlink works then `public/storage/media` path would redirect you to `storage/app/public/media`. But in the end the files need to be in `storage/app/public/media`. If you don't have a symlink then run `php artisan storage:link` to create it.

Comment: How can I confirm symlink works? I know that I created it by running `php artisan storage:link` in terminal at my project directory, but not sure why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: Run `ls -la` from your `public` folder. The `public/storage` folder should be linked to `storage/app/public`.

Comment: Okay it looks like this is so, the last line when I run that command is `lrwxr-xr-x   1 me  staff       57 May 23 20:15 storage -> /Users/me/projects/specificproject/storage/app/public`

Comment: Seems fine. Try accessing the image from `storage/app/public/media` folder from `http://localhost:8000/storage/media/imagename.jpg`. Change the server based on your setup.

Comment: I am using Valet so I'm not exactly sure what my setup would entail here. I'm thinking it's just `localhost/storage/media/filename.jpg`, which returned a  `404 - Not Found` error

Comment: I have been playing around with this and still have not been able to solve. I tried `mysite.dev/storage/media/image.jpg` and created a route `Route::get('/storage/media/image.jpg', function () {

 return;
 
});` but the page returns blank. Do you have any idea what the issue could be here? I have also tried `return view();` but get this error `UnexpectedValueException in Response.php line 450:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.`

Comment: It's clear that your symlink is not working. The first route with blank page is because you return nothing. Second time `return view();` returns the view object, so the error. The first route would not have worked if you have the image in the folder. Because in laravel you can't create routes with the same path as the folders in your public folder.

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working, I just tried in terminal to recreate it and I get the message that the link has already been created. What are my options besides a fresh larvae install and migrating all of my files?

Answer (score -1):

For Laravel 5, open your terminal on project's root and run:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This will create a link between the **storage/app** and **public** folders.